# How can i convert C# Security.GetSecureString function in PHP

Tags: c#, php, security, ldap

my conpany uses an LDAP autentication using c#, now the asked me to make a php program, but i found a problem, they used this line to encript the password:

```
  sec_pwd = Security.GetSecureString(user_pwd);
```

Do you know if there is a way to obtain the same result in php?

Comment: Check what a [SecureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-5.0) really is, you will notice the code your company uses is flawed because you have your password in plain text in the `user_pwd` variable, defeating the `SecureString` purpose.

Comment: To expand on what Cleptus wrote, ignore the whole concept of `GetSecureString` and consider `sec_pwd` to be a copy of `user_pwd`

Comment: Ok, but i cant login because of password check fail